# jQuery scrollLeft not working on hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a big container DIV that has many other element in it and has scroll bar. I get the amount of scrollLeft when the DIV is visible but when i hide the element `scrollLeft()` returns 0.

Same way if I set the value in `scrollLeft(100)` I end up getting 0.

[Follow the Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/jwzm1zut/)

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.hide()` sets `display: none;` to the element it's applied to. Elements that are `display: none;` have dimensions of `0px` by `0px` and are treated by the rendering engine as elements that are currently not part of the `DOM`. Thus you wouldn't be able to retrieve the current scroll position, unless you temporarily show the element.

```
$("#parent").show();
console.log($("#parent").scrollLeft());
$("#parent").hide();
```

[Here's the updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jwzm1zut/2/)

Answer (score 1):

How do you hide your div?
Try to use

```
visibility:hidden
```

instead of

```
display :none
```

because Visibility handles the visibility of the DIV but keep space, and  display handles space does the DIV occupies.